# Discord.JS Announce Command Issue

Tags: module, discord.js, fs

I'm trying to build an announce command for my bot using a rich embed.

Here is my `announce.js` file:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'announce',
    description: 'Send an announcement.',
    guildOnly: true,
    execute(message, args) {
        console.log("embedding")


        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle("Announcement")
            .setDescription("A Staff member has sent an announcement")
            .setColor(0x00AE86)
            .setFooter("Guardian", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phantomdev-github/Resources/master/Discord%20Bots/Guardian/src/avatar.png")
            .setThumbnail("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phantomdev-github/Resources/master/Discord%20Bots/Guardian/src/avatar.png")
            .setTimestamp()
            .setURL("https://github.com/phantomdev-github/Resources/tree/master/Discord%20Bots/Guardian")
            .addBlankField(true)
            .addField("Announcement", "message contents here", false))
        message.channel.send({ embed });
    }
};
```

I rebuilt it since the post it and took me a while to get back to this post. I'm trying to rebuild all of my messages from my bot into rich embeds. Thus the different code. I've also simplified my `fs` command and events handler.

`indexjs`

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { token } = require('./token.json');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    console.log(file,command)
}

fs.readdir('./events/', (err, files) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    files.forEach(file => {
        if(!file.endsWith('.js')) return;
        const eventFunction = require(`./events/${file}`);
        console.log(eventFunction)
        eventFunction.execute(client)
    });
});

client.login(token);
```

`message.js`

```js
const { prefix } = require('./prefix.json');

module.exports = {
    name: 'message',
    description: 'client message event.',
    execute:function(client) {
        client.on('message',message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
        if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

        try {
            client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
                }
})

}};
```

Basically I need to know what to put for `"message contents here"` to make it post the message typed into the `#announcements` channel.

My question is how to I make it place the announcement message into the `.addField` section of the richEmbed?

Would it be something along the lines of this?

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'announce',
    description: 'Send an announcement to the specified channel.',
    guildOnly: true,
    execute(message, args) {
        console.log("embedding")
    enter code here
        if(args.length < 2) return /* error message */;


    let channel = message.mentions.channels.first();
    if(!channel) return ;

    let announcement = args.slice(1).join(" ");

            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle("Notice!")
            .setDescription("Announcememnt from PhantomDEV Staff!")
            .setColor(0x00AE86)
            .setFooter("Guardian", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phantomdev-github/Resources/master/Discord%20Bots/Guardian/src/avatar.png")
            .setThumbnail("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phantomdev-github/Resources/master/Discord%20Bots/Guardian/src/avatar.png")
            .setTimestamp()    
            .setURL("https://github.com/phantomdev-github/Resources/tree/master/Discord%20Bots/Guardian")
            .addBlankField(true)
            .addField("Message", "", false);

        message.channel.send({ embed });
        .catch(console.error);
};
```

Comment: `module.exports.execute()` doesn't use `command` or `args` parameters, and those variables aren't defined anywhere within the function. `message.mentions.channels()` is also not a method; `message.mentions.channels` is a property returning a Collection, so perhaps you mean `message.mentions.channels.first()`. Consider an overview of the [Discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) to help you get started.

Comment: well first issue I'm already seeing with that is mine doesn't use ``module.exports.execute``. it strictly requires just ``module.exports = {`` Any attempt at using a different format breaks the command. So I have to make it work with ``module.exports = {``

Also my command and args variables are called via my ``index.js`` file. It is set to use ``fs`` to call that part in order to shorten the code used in the commands themselves.

Comment: `execute` is defined as a property of `module.exports` and can therefore be denoted as `module.exports.execute`.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your `message` event, use this line to call the execution of the command...

```js
command.execute(message, args);
```

Define your `execute` function to use the `args` parameter that you need. Also, [`Collection.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=first) is the method you're looking for when declaring `channel`. Your function should look like so...

```js
execute: function(message, args) {
  if (args.length < 2) return /* error message */;

  // Careful using this; if just an announcement is provided
  // and it mentions a channel, that channel will be used.
  let channel = message.mentions.channels.first();
  if (!channel) return /* error message */;

  let announcement = args.slice(1).join(" ");

  channel.send(announcement)
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

There's no need to check that the command is "announce" in the execution function, because it'll only be called if it is.

Comment: awesome that did exactly what I was needing! Thanks.

Comment: Yo my bot structure hs been updated and the command needs to be refixed again xD. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @JoshuaVL1988 The concept remains the same. The code inside of the `execute` function should remain very similar. What part do you need help with?

Comment: I don't know how to get it to put the message into the embed basically.

Comment: I updated the original post in here to show what I have, what I'm trying and what I'm wanting to get out of it. But basically I want the `announce.js` to post a rich embed to the `#announcements` channel in my discord containing the message typed *without* having to specify the channel.

Comment: @JoshuaVL1988 To default to a channel named `announcements`, you could set your `channel` variable to `message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === 'announcements')` when a channel isn't explicitly provided. To add the announcement to the rich embed, simply use the same `announcement` variable as the field value (`.addField('Message:', announcement)`).